# Import js file from node_modules in vue-cli app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, node-modules, vue-cli

I've installed this with npm : https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts

Doing `npm install hchs-vue-charts`

Which is a package to make charts in my views.

[image: Here is my project and I want to use ChartJS on the Dashboard.vue component]

I just want to know how to import this lib from `node_modules` in a single component in Vuejs with the Vue-cli app (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) because in their examples they do it with an instance of Vue.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must install module in **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCharts from 'hchs-vue-charts'

Vue.use(VueCharts)
```

then use component everywhere in you app, like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <chartjs-line></chartjs-line>
  </div>
</template>
```

other components in lib:

```
<chartjs-bar/>
<chartjs-horizontal-bar/>
<chartjs-radar/>
<chartjs-polar-area/>
<chartjs-pie/>
<chartjs-doughnut/>
```

Comment: There is likely some other config. Vue does not find all libs like this.

Comment: These components provided by  VueCharts and registered globally. See https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts/blob/433c747fdf51ad12604df0cb285820c8cdd916c7/src/vue-charts.js#L8

Answer (score 2):

In `main.js` import vue-charts and init the plugin like this:

```
import VueCharts from 'hchs-vue-charts'

Vue.use(VueCharts)
```